# Lie algebra of vector fields on a manifold - perfect?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras, vector-fields

I feel like what I'm about to ask should be very well-known in the literature, but I just cannot find a good source, neither in my usual literature nor on stackexchange. Recall that a topological Lie algebra $L$ is called *perfect* if $[L,L] = L$. It is called *topologically perfect* if the relation holds only in closure, so $\overline{[L,L]} = L$.

**Question:** Is the Lie algebra of vector fields $\Gamma(TM)$ over a smooth manifold $M$ perfect? For compact manifolds, I think this should be true, using partitions of unity to reduce to neighbourhoods where $TM$ is locally trivial. More generally, I suppose at least topological perfectness should hold (w.r.t the locally convex $C^\infty(M)$-topology for $\Gamma(TM)$), but I'm not sure how to prove this. I was also thinking about using the implication "semisimple $\implies$ perfect", but I am not sure how many of the usual equivalences of the semisimple-property still hold in infinite dimensional Lie algebras. Anyone got an easy proof idea or a reference?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may look at the book of Banyaga on the question. He has shown that the connected component of the group of diffeomorpisms of a compact manifold is simple (or more generally diffeomorphisms with compact support), so its Lie algebra is simple.

https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780792344759